# Parsing JSON Field Using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

Forgive the naive nature, but I'm making small strides deconstructing a SwiftyJSON example project to fit my needs.  Right now, I have an AppDelegate file with the following;

```
 import UIKit
 import SwiftyJSON

 @UIApplicationMainclass AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let viewController = navigationController.topViewController as! ViewController

    let url = NSURL(string: "http://myurl/json/")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue(), completionHandler: {(response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            let json = JSON(data: data!)

            for (key, subJson) in json {
                if let userName = subJson["userName"].string {
                    println(userName)
                }
            }

            viewController.json = json
        }
        else {
            println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })

    return true
    }
}
```

This appears to be very successful in printing the "userName" field when I run the app.  Where I'm hitting a roadblock now is figuring out how to pass my "userName" data to my ViewController file, and have it display as a textLabel in my cell.  Despite my efforts, I can only get the cell to be labeled "null," leading me to believe that what's being parsed in my AppDelegate isn't accessible from the ViewController file.  Would that sound right?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you do this inside your `AppDelegate`, why not make a class for the request and access it wherever you want?.You can use dependecies injection, singleton or anything you want to access to the class

Comment: Thanks, Victor!  I was hoping to avoid the creation of a class, mainly because of my newness on the subject and the small strides I'm trying to make.  If that would be a more acceptable way of parsing the data, and sharing it between files in the project, then it may be best for me to approach learning that method.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, but if you want the solution I put solves your problem of load a `UIIViewController` from the `AppDelegate`.

Comment: Thanks, Victor.  I've added the code you provided in your answer to my AppDelegate, which does load and not present any errors, but I can't seem to find the right verbiage I would use in the ViewController.swift file to actually parse out certain fields.  It's as if the variables I am creating in the AppDelegate (such as "userName") are not being called by the ViewController.

Comment: The problem is the reference , it's not the same the `ViewController` unless you set has to be the rootViewController, see updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try access to the `UIViewController` you want it in the following way instead:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject :AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    // You need to cast to the name of your ViewController to acces to its fields after.
    var initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController") as! ViewController

    // set the JSON value to the ViewController here.        
    initialViewController.json = json

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

You have to set the **Storyboard ID** for the `UIViewController` you want in your Interface Builder. In the above way you secure the reference to hold , setting the `UIViewController` you want it as your `rootViewController`.

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks, Victor.  I think I'm probably just in over my head with understanding.  So, to be clear, this would fall at the top of my AppDelegate file?  And if so, what would I be calling in my ViewController to actually reference the data?

Comment: When you present the `UIViewController` entitled `ViewController` in the above way, the reference stay and you can access all its fields from the `AppDelegate` in the beginning. What do you need isn't pass a value?

Comment: I got it!  Thanks for your time and patience, Victor!  You're a real hero and certainly helped me find some information I was not able to locate elsewhere (and I promise I searched!)